# Cannot install openssh-server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, dependencies

```
root@abacus-desktop:~# apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  openssh-server: Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) but 1:5.3p1-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
  wireshark: Depends: libsmi2ldbl but it is not going to be installed
  wireshark-common: Depends: libsmi2ldbl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Tried `aptitude`?  It seems to be a little cleverer, it will probably offer you some alternatives fixing the issue.  (Run `aptitude`, search (with the `/` key) for `openssh-server`), press `+`, ...)

Comment: I did like you said, and there is #Broken: 2

Comment: Doesn't it suggest a fix? ([Have a look here on how this could work, analogously.](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch01s01s04.html))

Comment: OK thanks all. It works now! I removed the packages wireshark, wireshark-common and another package interfering with libsmi21db1. Re-installed everything, not it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is really vague.

Did you try to run `apt-get -f install` as suggested to fix the broken dependencies? Did you mix different versions in your sources.list?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newb to ubuntu. What is sources.list?

Comment: The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` where the repositories of your package manager are configured.

Comment: With apt-get install -f: <br/><br/> Unpacking libsmi2ldbl (from .../libsmi2ldbl_0.4.8+dfsg2-2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libsmi2ldbl_0.4.8+dfsg2-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/smicache', which is also in package libsmi 0:0.4.                     5-4
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsmi2ldbl_0.4.8+dfsg2-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: There seems to be a broken package, either `libsmi2ldbl` or `libsmi`. Both provide `/usr/bin/smicache` and thus conflict with each other. Try removing one of those two packages.

Comment: What command to use to remove the package? sorry...i just started using linux 1 week ago. is it apt-get remove package

Comment: Either `apt-get remove <package>` or `dpkg -r <package>`. Note: this help system isn't made for such long discussions, better ask your question in an ubuntu forum.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with 13.04 (but it was instead complaining that the `openssh-client` to be installed is NEWER than the one required).

Turns out that the software sources was configured to download from a servers local to the country where I'm residing (Kuwait).

I solved it by opening Ubuntu Software Center application, then going to the "Edit > Software Sources", then in the Ubuntu Software tab I change the Donwload from drop down list to "Main Server".

I then ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrad`e and finally `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and this time it installed without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your repository dependencies are broken. Try to clean your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Which is a text file that has all your repositories of packages. Probably you have edited it.

Then do an `apt-get update`. You should tell us your *Ubuntu* version, and why seems you have another dependencies broken like *Wireshark*.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and when I try to install Wireshark, it says 
apt-get: /home/thot/SC/ST/bin/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /home/thot/SC/ST/bin/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /home/thot/SC/ST/bin/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8)
apt-get: /home/thot/SC/ST/bin/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8)

Comment: Here is my souces.list      
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse

Comment: it seems you have an strange configuration of your distro installation. something is wrong. it seems you have your library path placed wrong. it is a fresh installation?

Comment: yes it is a fresh installation

Comment: Try a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise" instead.  It's 2 years newer and is the latest Long Term Service release, from April this year.  Also unless you intend to regularly rebuild source packages, comment out the deb-src lines in your /etc/apt/sources.list - save time downloading and parsing them every time you run `apt-get update`

Comment: as logoff hinted at, your libraries look really messed up. try unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH if it's set, check `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` to make sure there's nothing odd in them (like lib dirs in /home/thot), then run ldconfig.  finally try the apt-get install again.  all of this should be done as root, BTW, either in a root shell or with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing packages are probably in repositories that are commented out in your sources.list (i.e. they are not enabled). Update your repositories first, then try to install again.